# Integration for Fourier coefficients of $x$

Tags: calculus, integration

To compute the Fourier coefficients of $x$, I was trying to integrate $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi xe^{-inx}dx$$ How to integrate this? (I already did it, and I'm posting my answer just to keep the records and possibly help others in the future.)

Comment: So what is your question? You've posted an answer to it.

Comment: @T.Bongers I just did it, and I'm posting it to keep my records as well as possibly help others in the future :)

Comment: So you're not actually asking for anyone to answer, since you don't have a question?

Comment: @T.Bongers Right, not really asking for an answer, except if someone has interesting comments/answers to make, that would be very welcome (as I see N.S. just did). I hope it's [okay](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I used integration by parts.  $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi xe^{-inx}dx=x\frac{e^{-inx}}{-in}-\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{e^{-inx}}{-in}dx$$

The first term is $\dfrac{i}{n}(\pi(\cos(-n\pi)+i\sin(-n\pi)+\pi(\cos(n\pi)+i\sin(n\pi))=\dfrac{2\pi i}{n}\cos(n\pi)$

The  second term is $-\dfrac{1}{n^2}(\cos(-n\pi)+i\sin(-n\pi)-\cos(n\pi)-i\sin(-n\pi))=\dfrac{2i}{n^2}\sin(n\pi)$

EDIT: As N.S. helpfully pointed out, when $n=0$ this should be done separately. So it's $\int_{-\pi}^\pi xdx=0$. Also, for other $n$ the answer is $\dfrac{2\pi i}{n}\cos(n\pi)-\dfrac{2i}{n}\sin(n\pi)=\dfrac{2\pi i(-1)^n}{n}$

Comment: What is $\sin(n \pi)$?  What is $\cos(n \pi)$? You know them.... Also, what happens when $n=0$? You divide by $0$ ;)